# what statistical test should I use /psychology research

Tags: t-test

I have two groups male and female. Both of the same size, both will get  the same treatment. I want to see if the female  or male improved at all  after treatment and by how much  (measurement taken before and after the treatment) and then I want to compare the results  between male /female to see which group improved more. What test should i use? .  I know that paired T test can give me the results for women and men separately but I do not know how to compare  two groups together after.

Comment: You _could_ put everything into an ANOVA with factors Gender and Before/After. But the quick answer is to test M vs F with a **_two-sample_** test on the After-Before differences.

Comment: Hi Bruce  thank you for your reply. I am really bad at statistic. Do you mean  difference in score between after and before eg 8-3 =5 and use this score for  Fvs M two sample t test?